# How to calculate object real life location from self driving car?

Tags: python, coordinate-system, coordinates, gps

I have a video made from a car together with GPS information (location coordinates, altitude, speed, track to true North degrees and other. Also I have a 3gf file of g-sensor but I’m not able to parse it). I ran object detection and now I need to calculate coordinates of the detected object (latitude and longitude). However, I can’t find a formula for how to do it. Can anyone give me some examples on how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Can you calculate how far away the detected object is from the camera? If so, you could turn it into a geometry problem. Detected Object is X distance away from camera location, Y degrees left/right of the centerline direction. Use this trigonometry with the known camera lat/long to calculate object's lat/long.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can calculate distance. As I looked for formula for this distance task, I need a real object size. I know real size for 1 object class, but don't know for others and there is no guarantee that this known height object will be in every image that will be analysed.

Comment: Can you track a detected object until it goes out of view at the sides of your image? Because the edge of your field of view should be a fixed point in relation to the car. So then you would just have to figure out that distance calculation once (and it might be part of the camera specifications).

Comment: Yes, but objects can be in a bit different places, the distance from car can differ. But possibly I can find the distance for some limited points and later assign values. However, that won't be very accurate but could be a start.

Comment: You might want to consider what level of accuracy is necessary to answer your question(s). Some how are these detected objects being used? For example if you represent that gate as a point there's already some abstraction occurring. How much can that point be misaligned before it starts to impact your overall problem solving? For example maybe off by a few meters doesn't matter, whereas being off by 30 meters would matter.

Comment: I think that in best situation +-1 meter would be great (doesn't keeping in mind GPS error), but it could be +-5m at worst case not more. I'm planning to take a center point of gate, so yes, there will be some additional error too.

Comment: Assuming the locality follows any kind of standardization, the road markings should have some known length that could be used to approximate distance from the camera, perhaps? Is it possible to repeat your calculation from multiple frames to try and average out the results?

Comment: I could take some objects for reference, but it can be noisy, because some lines can be not full because of their age

Comment: Can you usually see your objects from at least 2 different angles (pictures)? If so, then perhaps there would be a way to use the bearing of the object in both images, and extend those bearings from the 2 pictures lat/lon, and the intersection of those bearings would give you the desired coordinate.

Comment: Yes, I can see from different pictures at different time (it's a video stream).

Comment: Do you have the pitch/roll/yaw angles for your images? I guess they aren't necessarily level, right?

Comment: No, but I have car orientation to North

Comment: I see. Then you might be a bit limited in terms of achievable accuracy. Try to see if you can measure horizontal angles from the center of your images to the object, that might help you locate them.